# Two persons pick three different out of ten, probability of them being all different?

Tags: probability

I'm either failing at understanding basic probabilities or have a problem with software PRNG.

If person A picks $3$ different numbers from $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ and person B then also picks $3$ different numbers from $\{1,\ldots,10\}$, what is the probability that person B didn't pick a single number identical to person A's numbers?

The picking is random in both case, but with the constraint that the 3 numbers have to be different. I take it there's $C(10,3)$ ways to pick $3$ different numbers out of ten, but this shouldn't influence the probability I'm looking for.

Is $p = \left(\frac7{10}\right)^3$?

If so it should give $p = 0.342999$. But then when I try with a PRNG I get values constantly differing from that, no matter the seed and no matter the PRNG.

Comment: btw this is not homework...

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ picks three items, $B$ will only pick three items different from the ones A has chosen if he picks them all from the remaining $7$. This number is given by the binomial coefficient $$\binom 7 3=\frac {7!}{3!4!}$$ The total number of ways $B$ can pick three items from ten is $$\binom {10} 3=\frac {10!}{3!7!}$$

The probability of picking three different items is then $$\frac {\binom 7 3}{\binom {10} 3}=\frac {7!}{3!4!}\cdot \frac{3!7!}{10!}=\frac {7\cdot6\cdot5}{10\cdot9\cdot8}=\frac 7{24}$$

Comment: thanks a lot, can't upvote you because I don't have 15 rep : (

Answer (score 0):

Well... A chooses $3$ of $10$ is $\frac1{10C3}$.
B chooses other than A's choice is $1-P(A)$.
Hence the answer is $\left(\frac1{10C3}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{10C3}\right)$.